# How to force explicit `http://example.com` to https on nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

How can I force `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` on nginx?

This is my current config, it works only if type `example.com` it redirects to https as spected, but if I type with explicit scheme http  `http://example.com` does not redirect to https.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    ...

}
```

Comment: @Bernhard That question does not have an acepted answer :( nevetheless the question will be if its possible to force explicity typed "http://" to https. if you want to try: `http://vislab.center` does not work but `vislab.center` does

Comment: That's strange as I would have thought that they were identical requests. Have you reset browser's cache?

Comment: @IgnacioMartínez Sorry if this was not helpful. Removed my comment.